# Use Jenkins plugin in tuleap when Jenkins use LDAP Authentication

Tags: authentication, jenkins, tuleap, openldap

I want to use Tuleap(Jenkins/hudson plugin in tuleap) and Jenkins with ldap Authentication
by default when i disable Jenkins Authentication every thing work and integration is ok but 
when i activate jenkins Ldap authentication the integration fails.
i use "Authentication Tokens API Plugin" and "Build Authorization Token Root Plugin" to handle token authentication but its not working.
Please advise me?

Answer (score 0):

You should configure the permissions at Jenkins side so "Build" action for the given job can be done by "Anonymous".